# how to change links of html file to local links

Tags: python, html, file, urllib2, urllib

I'm making my own web crawler on python 2.7   that download a website to a path in my computer and I save the files in similar way they are saved on the folder of the site on the server for example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=python+how+to+change+links+of+html+file+to+local+links

I will make a directory of stackoverflow inside it a directory of questions and inside it the html file of this page...

How I can change the links to the pages in the internet to link to pages I downloaded if they already exist on my computer?

For example if there is :
`<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions">` so I will change this html code through python to
`<a href="/questions">` or something like this..

I don't know if it helps but this is the function I use to download on a single file:
 def downloadFile(path , url):

```
try :
    print "Downloading  : " + url
    path=path + urlparse(url).path 
    path , fileName = pathNameSplit(path)


    make_sure_path_exists(path)



    print "trying to downoad " + fileName 
    if (fileName.count(".") == 0 ):fileName = fileName + ".html"
    #pickle.dump( url2Html(url) , open( path + fileName, "w" ))

    urllib.urlretrieve(url, path + fileName)
    print "Download of  " + url + " Completed"
except Exception:
    print "Sometihng occured in the download of " + url
```

Comment: if i were you i would use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead of urllib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you grab a **link** and save the page to a **path**, save the link and the path to a dictionary.

You'd also need to make sure of a few things
1. that each path is unique to a link (kind of optional, but really useful, i guess)
2. that you didn't overwrite into that path any other page from another link

Then, after you're done crawling, you need to edit "manually" (of course, with some python code) the links in your downloaded files, to point instead to your files on the file system.

By editing manually, what I mean is using some module ( `re` ) to search and replace strings inside your downloaded files.

After you do this transformation, you will lose the reference to the web pages you which were the original source of the files.

If you need to retain the original online url, you could simply give each URL a unique ID, and store that in your local DB (together with your file system path - where you downloaded the files, of course)..

If you can't do this yourself, ask for more help.

**[edit]**
well with the *re* module, you could do the following

```
import re

html_file_content = u"asdf 1234 this should contain the source code of a html page that you downloaded"
pattern = u"http://the-url-from-which-you-downloaded-the-html-file.com"
path = u"d:/whatever/path/where/you/downloaded/the/html/file"
new_file_content = re.sub(pattern, path, a)
```

The name `new_file_content` will have the source file, with the file system path instead of a link... be sure to concatenate a file:// to the beginning of the `path` variable, so the browser can recognize this as a valid link (such as `file://d:/downloads/python_crawler`, not just `d:/downloads/python_crawler`

Comment: Can you help with the part of :
"using some module ( re ) to search and replace strings inside your downloaded files."

Comment: I'm guessing 're.sub(pattern, path, a)' should be 're.sub(pattern, path, html_file_content)'?